# Convert S3M, XM and MOD files to flac/mp3 preserving tags

Tags: windows, linux, audio, macos, media-converter

Remember the modules of the past? MOD, S3M, XM, ST? Great, so do I! I have thousands of modules in my file shares :-).

But… now I'd love to convert all my collected modules into playable files in an updated format, with some of the module tag info preserved.

How can I, using MacOS, Windows (Azure client), Ubuntu or FreeBSD (using command line), convert all module files in a folder into a lossless format (or mp3) and preserve some of the tags in the modules in the destination format?

My next step is to place all files into a Plex share :-D

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the tags (did not play with `mod` files for decades, but you can try [xrecode](https://xrecode.com/). This software can convert `mod` files to `flac` for sure, do not have examples of other formats to test.